# How to repair and rebuild .htaccess in sugarcrm

Tags: php, .htaccess, sugarcrm

I am testing rest api in SugarCRM. In order to use crm rest api, I added :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

to .htaccess file and rebuilt .htaccess File. However, it did not give me solution. I am still getting error message with the following content:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.crm.loc/custom/clients/base/api/get_account.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: what you can , can explain so i can give you solutions for that .

Comment: I created rest api and tested it on local server. However, when I uploaded code to remote server, it did not working as if Access-Control-Allow-Origin was not set

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I put following code to the top of rest api code file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

It worked for me.